# What can I do to stem the growing number of rumours?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, urban-shadows

So in Urban Shadows at the start of each session each player is spotlighted a faction and has to provide a rumour about that faction to the MC.

This is great but the problem is that with 4 players we get 4 new rumours every session when realistically we can only tackle about 1 a session, leaving 3 new unhandled rumours.  That means at 3 sessions in we have a enourmous number of things that we have to deal with.

Note that there is an option to simply skip this move, but this option seems rather un-fun. Since rumours are the main drive of the game having nothing change since last session just never seems to fit the story very well.

What are some ways that we could stem the constant generation of new rumours while still keeping the rumours compelling and relevant?

Answer (score 14):

### Tie your rumours together so that they can be tackled together

Here is one thing I've tried a bit which aleviates the problem a bit:  You make it so that new rumours relate to old rumours in a way that tackling one tackles another.

For example let's say a player was spotlit wild and they came up with the following rumour:

> The homeless down by the 93<sup>rd</sup> street station have been talking about a summoning on the Ⓧ line between 93<sup>rd</sup> and 115<sup>th</sup>.  Apparently some lesser demons have been working together to summon Iniúchadh, the Unholy Surveyor.

Now if the next player is spotlit for example power they could come up with the related rumour:

> I've heard that some of the higher wizards have seen this as an opportunity to push their influence into the North side.  The summoning ceremony will make the demons weak giving them the opportunity to seize the area.  Mendel, the Wiser, specifically is rounding up a party of wizards to target the ceremony directly.

Now if the party engages with one of the rumours they have to engage with the other.  Go to stop the summoning and you have to stop the wizard's power grab.  Go to stop the power grab and you're right in the thick of a demon summoning ritual.

With rumours structured like this it really is possible to tackle more than one a session, maybe not 4 but it certainly improves the situation.

Comment: Corollary: if a prior rumor wasn't handled, introduce a new rumor about how it's developed.

Answer (score 3):

### Rumors are yours to propose, but need not be yours to deal with.

You don't need to treat the rumors you introduce as your characters' responsibility to resolve. It's assumed in the rumor roll that your character has dealt to some extent with the rumor already, coming out ahead on a clean hit, entangled on a partial, or on the receiving end of unfortunate consequences on a miss. Rumors reflect things that are happening in the city, and anybody in the city can engage with them, **including the MC, who plays the rest of the city**.

Plenty of MC moves can take rumors and run with them:

- *surface a conflict (ancient or modern)*
- *reveal a deal done in their absence*
- *mobilize resources to shift the odds*
- *lock down, exploit, or claim a place of power*

And that's just the basic stuff. If your MC has a storm or storms developing, odds are at least one of its threats is going to have a threat move that is capable of bringing elements of the rumor into the storm.

If your sessions only run for an hour or two, you might not have playing time to even address each of the rumors, regardless of who runs with them. If this is the case, it may be better to treat multiple play periods as a single session, for all that it might remove the neat brackets from any given night's start or end of play.